# basic postgres csv import--track bad tuples

Tags: postgresql, csv, error-logging

This ought to be basic, but I have a flat csv file with 6 million rows that I import to postgres 9.1 and things are all 'good', except that I am missing about 3 million records, silently, when import is done.

I initially thought there was a bad delimiter or end of file character that caused an abrupt stop around record 3.4 million or something similar, but the ids (native to the data, not auto-generated) suggests that the missed rows are not sequential, but scattered throughout the file.

I want to pre-process it in python or pandas, but my relative illiteracy with postgres with respect to logging errors of my `COPY` or `\copy` commands means I don't know which are the offending records.

Sorry this is not a reproducible example--hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction easily to logging errors/silently rejected tuples (and possibly the reason why?)--I saw the rejected [patch](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Error_logging_in_COPY), but there is presumably some way to do this with the existing tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try setting [log_statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT):

`log_statement(ddl)`